# Debian Wheezy with default Kernel (3.2.0-4-amd64) high load average

Tags: linux, io, load, cpu

I have recently upgraded to a new machine and to Debian Wheezy.

Everything ist running fine, except that even with low actual load, the load average is too high.

Example:

```
14:29:35 up  9:49,  1 user,  load average: 1.96, 2.22, 2.14
```

This happens even tho all components are at a low load (almost no I/O and all CPU Cores are <50%)

top:

```
top - 14:30:31 up  9:50,  1 user,  load average: 2.38, 2.32, 2.18
Tasks: 156 total,   3 running, 153 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 28.2 us,  1.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 69.8 id,  0.4 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  32878740 total,  8036624 used, 24842116 free,   106544 buffers
KiB Swap: 16768892 total,        0 used, 16768892 free,  2897400 cached
```

iotop:

```
Total DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE:    1004.39 B/s
```

vmstat:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
0  0      0 24809288 107236 2921816    0    0    10     1  102  138 17  2 81  0
1  0      0 24809364 107244 2921908    0    0     6     6 14334 15108 24  1 75  0
4  0      0 24808784 107260 2921952    0    0     2    16 14407 15222 24  1 74  0
0  0      0 24808660 107272 2922096    0    0     4    14 14570 15373 26  1 73  0
1  0      0 24808156 107280 2922220    0    0     0    13 14783 15499 27  1 72  0
2  0      0 24807420 107292 2922684    0    0     0    23 14590 15344 26  1 72  0
```

uname -r:

```
3.2.0-4-amd64
```

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the answer, but I'm having the same issue and can see an increasing number of bug reports being filed around the 3.2.0 kernel on Wheezy. E.g.: http://www.willdurness.com/high-load-in-wheezy-high-interrupts-for-rescheduling-interrupts-and-timer/

Comment: we're having similar issue with the same kernel `uname -v`: `#1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3`. There seems to be also a problem with NAT: http://mark.orbum.net/2014/07/29/fix-slow-network-nat-after-debian-kernel-update-3-2-0-4/. So far we have no idea what's wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Load average is usually the number of process waiting for execution, as in the queue.

As it doesn't seem to be a problem with CPU and I/O, I would expect to be something like a shared memory semaphore, or a network dependent code.

Try to see what processes are with:

```
# top -b -n 1 | awk '{if (NR <=7) print; else if ($8 == "D") {print; count++} } END {print "Total status D: "count}'
```